# app is listening but socket.io won't connect

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

My first time working with websockets. I've been working on this for 2 days... :(

I have a new Centos7/redhat/linux vps server running Cyberpanel/LiteSpeed and I cannot get a very simple example socket.io code block to work!!! Of course, my code works like a champ in development. whew.

- It's a React app frontend with a nodejs endpoint.
- All of my node_modules are present and accounted for.
- I'm running the app outside the public_html directory if that matters.
- Status codes for the socket.io GET requests are 200.
- No CORS errors (but right now I'm not using any endpoints)
- It's polling.
- I've unblocked port 5000 in the firewall.
- I have rebooted LiteSpeed.
- I have the latest versions of socket.io and socket.io-client.
- I've tried require('https') instead of require('http').
- I've tried using app.listen(port) as the server instead of require('http').createServer(app), or require('http').Server(app)
- I've tried almost infinite variations of endpoints.
- I've tried panic and depression.

In this example, the app runs, and prints 'This always works' in the terminal, but that's it. 'My self-esteem' is missing.

Here's an example app.js:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

console.log('This always works')

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
     console.log('my self-esteem')
     ...
}

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Definitely listening on port ${port}`))
```

I don't believe the client side is the problem... (I think it is maybe a server issue) but, here's the basic setup for client.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const pleaseDoSomething = () => {

     const socket = io() //endpoints seem useless

     socket.emit(send some data) //irrelevant right now
     socket.on(receive some data) //irrelevant right now
     return (irrelevance and uselessness)
}
export default pleaseDoSomething
```

I've even tried the simplest of code, which prints 'always visible' in the terminal and nothing else!!!

```
var io = require('socket.io')(5000);

console.log('always visible')

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('my self-worth')
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('my self-worth')
});
```

What in the world am I doing wrong? I've read all of the tutorials and stackoverflow answers. I've literally copied code from tutorials. Nothing is working! Any suggestions or comments would be GREATLY appreciated because I'm out of ideas and things to google.

Thank you in advance!
~Someone who doesn't know a lot about servers (or websockets, apparently)

Comment: If it works locally, but not in your hosting, then it's probably because of a network configuration in your hosting provider.  It is often required that proxies be configured to specifically allow certain headers that websockets use or to allow persistent connections that are not automatically killed after a short while.  I would do some searching on configuring your hosting site to allow webSocket or socket.io connections.

Comment: Thank you for the response!! At least I have something else to research now. I had run into a wall...